# Wordpress remove post attributes

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to remove the template from post attributes in wordpress admin panel or how can I remove post attributes dropdown for specific user roles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this not remove but hide attributes

```
function hide_meta_box_attributes( $hidden, $screen) {

    $hidden[] = 'pageparentdiv';
    return $hidden;

} 
add_filter('hidden_meta_boxes', 'hide_meta_box_attributes', 10, 2);
```